# RabbitMQ listener configuration - Unable to consume messages from Queue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I am having a problem in consuming messages from a queue. I have defined a listener but for some reason I am not able to consume any messages. I put breakpoints in the onMessage function but they never get hit. Here is my code files. Not sure what is wrong here:

Config file:

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="emailAccountConnectionFactory" host="localhost"/>

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="emailAccountConnectionFactory"
    exchange="emailAccountExchange" routing-key="email.Account"/>

<!--  <rabbit:admin connection-factory="emailAccountConnectionFactory" />-->

<rabbit:queue id="emailAccount" name="emailAccountQueue"/>

<rabbit:direct-exchange name="emailAccountExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="emailAccount" key="email.Account" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:direct-exchange>


<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="emailAccountConnectionFactory" acknowledge="none">
    <rabbit:listener ref="emailAccountAckListener" queue-names="emailAccountQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="emailAccountAckListener" class="start.web.listener.registration.EmailAccountAckListener" />
```

Message Listener class:

```
package start.web.listener.registration;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.Message;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.MessageListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import start.web.common.EventHandler;
import start.web.common.Events;

@Component
public class EmailAccountAckListener implements MessageListener {

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.print("Message Received");
        EventHandler.handler((Events) ((Map<String, Object>) 
           message).get("event"), ((Map<String, Object>) 
           message).get("message"));
    }
}
```

I am not able to hit breakpoint in the onMessage function. Also on the admin console of RabbitMQ I cannot see any consumer for my queue. I am not sure what I am doing wrong in the configuration. Here is the screenshot from the admin console for the queue:
[image]

Comment: Is the connection established? You can check it in management console/

Comment: If it means that I can send messages than yes it is. When I try to send a message from my code, I can see the message on the exchange as well as in the queue. I just don't see my listener consuming it. And I also don't see any consumers subscribed to my queue (from the screenshot). And that is where I am confused as to what may be wrong in the configuration

Comment: I would suggest to take a look into the logs. There might be some interesting about connection attempts. If not, try to turn on DEBUG logging level and see if the consumer is OK by definition

Comment: I think restarting the service is what was required. Magically started to work :)